# Watch window does not work

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, watch

When I want to use watch window I can not see the variable .I just see this message

> error: error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
>   error: 1 errors parsing expression

in watch window.

Comment: Which platform/IDE are you using? Could it be that you are watching a variable that has not yet been declared?

Comment: Also show us your code, a [mcve]

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 . Any variable that I use I receive this message.

Comment: I'm assuming you have set a breakpoint somewhere after the variable a has been declared and you can confirm (via hovering your mouse over said variable) that VS sees it as declared and initialized?

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can check the variable after declaration , I also use hovering mouse to see the result but I can not check the variable by watch window in my app. I guess the reason is that I use async and await and there are some tricks for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

[Debugging a Parallel Application in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-parallel-application)

Comment: I just have this problem that the watch window doesn't show the variables  in this project( REST API with Tizen Emulator ,multithreaded )  I checked other projects like Asp.net MVC and Console App. They are fine.